# resize event is not resizing image size as expected

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I have a image and I'm setting its height and width to 90% of the screen size while I am loading the HTML page. Now I want to adjust the image size when I resize the browser. Below is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setImageSize() {
     document.getElementById('rockImg').height=(screen.height)*.9;
     document.getElementById('rockImg').width=(screen.width)*.9;
  }
function resizeImageSize() {
     document.getElementById('rockImg').height=(document.body.clientHeight)*.9;
     document.getElementById('rockImg').width=(document.body.clientWidth)*.9;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setImageSize();" onresize="resizeImageSize();">
<img src="iRock_normal.png" id="rockImg" alt="iRock" onclick="greetByName();" />
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when I restore down the page, image size is getting changed as expected. However when I maximize the page, image height is holding the size same as when I restore down the page. And on each restore down + Maximize image size is getting smaller and smaller. Surprisingly it is happening only for height, not width.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm using chrome and it does resize as expected.

Comment: It doesn't really work for me, but that seems to be due to some wrong calculations -> http://jsfiddle.net/2VgHm/

Comment: I'm using chrome as well. It is not working for me. Also tested in IE10. Same problem. Please restore down and mazimize couple of times.

Comment: Yes Adeneo, that is the problem. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/2VgHm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="iRock_normal.png" id="rockImg" alt="iRock"/>
```

javascript:

```
var rockImg = document.getElementById('rockImg');

function resize() {
  var height = window.innerHeight*.9;
  var width = window.innerWidth*.9;
  rockImg.height= height;
  rockImg.width= width;
}

window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
```

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/OZiqufi/2/edit)

Inline js (onlick, etc, in your html) is not good practice - it should never be used. Your code would be easier to debug if you broke things up as I did above. Get the height, then apply the height, so that you can check what height is being calculated. That would have shown you that `clientHeight` wasn't giving you the value you expected. Further, your element can be cached in a variable so that you don't have to keep typing that long function to find it and hurting performance by searching the dom each time.